# List The Rows Where a Column Value Changes

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table like so:

```
+---------+----------------+--------+-------+-------+
| ITEM NO | EFFECTIVE DATE | HEIGHT | WIDTH | DEPTH |
+---------+----------------+--------+-------+-------+
|    1    |   01/01/1980   |   01   |   01  |   01  |
|    2    |   03/16/1985   |   02   |   02  |   02  |
|    1    |   07/03/1985   |   01   |   02  |   01  |
|    3    |   08/01/1986   |   03   |   03  |   03  |
|    1    |   08/03/1986   |   02   |   02  |   01  |
|    3    |   09/01/1986   |   04   |   03  |   03  |
|    2    |   09/20/1987   |   02   |   06  |   02  |
|    3    |   10/01/1987   |   04   |   04  |   03  |
|    1    |   06/18/2000   |   03   |   02  |   01  |
+---------+----------------+--------+-------+-------+
```

I need a query that returns the item number and date when just the item's height changes.  So, the results would be:

```
+---------+----------------+
| ITEM NO | EFFECTIVE DATE |
+---------+----------------+
|    1    |   01/01/1980   |
|    1    |   08/03/1986   |
|    1    |   06/18/2000   |
|    3    |   08/01/1986   |
|    3    |   09/01/1986   |
+---------+----------------+
```

So, item one's height changed three times on the dates shown (Including its initial height), item two's height hasn't changed so, it's ignored, and item three's height changed twice so, appears twice.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option; it

- finds previous `height` (per `item_no`, ordered by `date`) (line #14)
- sorts those values (line #15) - it will be used to display the very first value in a set

  - returns rows

    - whose "previous" and "current" height don't match (line#20)
    - which are first in the set (line #21)
    - but those items must be in a set that has different heights (lines #23 - 25) (this condition eliminates `item_no = 2`)

Here you go:

```
SQL> with test (item_no, effective_date, height) as
  2    (select 1, date '1980-01-01', '01' from dual union all
  3     select 2, date '1985-03-16', '02' from dual union all
  4     select 1, date '1985-07-03', '01' from dual union all
  5     select 3, date '1986-08-01', '03' from dual union all
  6     select 1, date '1986-08-03', '02' from dual union all
  7     select 3, date '1986-09-01', '04' from dual union all
  8     select 2, date '1987-09-20', '02' from dual union all
  9     select 3, date '1987-10-01', '04' from dual union all
 10     select 1, date '2000-06-18', '03' from dual
 11    ),
 12  temp as
 13    (select  item_no, effective_date, height,
 14             lag(height) over (partition by item_no order by effective_date) lheight,
 15             row_number() Over (partition by item_no order by effective_date) rn
 16     from test
 17    )
 18  select item_no, effective_date
 19  from temp
 20  where (   height <> lheight
 21         or rn = 1
 22        )
 23    and item_no in (select item_no from temp
 24                    group by item_no
 25                    having count(distinct height) > 1
 26                   )
 27  order by item_no, effective_date;

   ITEM_NO EFFECTIVE_
---------- ----------
         1 01/01/1980
         1 08/03/1986
         1 06/18/2000
         3 08/01/1986
         3 09/01/1986

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using multiple `analytical function`.

```
select item_no, effective_date 
from
(select item_no, 
        effective_date,
        Lag(height) over 
          (partition by item_no order by effective_date) as prev_height,
        Count(distinct height) over 
          (partition by item_no) as cnt_height
From your_table)
Where cnt_height > 1
And (prev_height is null or height <> prev_height);
```

Cheers!!